# Will installation of *BSD break my Ubuntu? And what about swap and bootloader mess up?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I have Windows 8 on my hdd(with it's system and boot partition), an Extended partition(D under Windows) from which I extended 2 more partitions - the one for Ubuntu(which is primary) and one for swap.

If I extend some more space and use it to install *BSD there, will it mess up with Win/Ubuntu, can I use same swap partition for both Ubuntu and *BSD, and what will happen with the bootloader?

Can I skip installing bootloader during installation on *BSD and will GRUB automatically find *BSD after it's installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot install BSD to the same partition as Ubuntu. It is possible to share swap partitions but you don't need to do so. This link covers some of that subject https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61587/freebsd-and-linux-shared-partitions

As for an installation step for BSD skipping the installation of a bootloader varies from distro to distro. You should be able to skip the step if you are installing the [debian version of BSD](https://wiki.debian.org/Debian_GNU/kFreeBSD) but I cannot speak for other distros.

Finally, yes, grub will be able to find BSD after installation. You just have to run the following command from Ubuntu when you are finished installing BSD:

```
sudo update-grub
```